# Passing array to array is yielding null values, what have I done wrong?

Tags: java

So I'm trying to write some code where I basically need to expand an array by one every time I pass through a loop. Yes I know that arrays are fixed size and that I need a new array each time. I'm also aware that if I used a list rather than an array I wouldn't be having any issues however I am being forced to use an array.

My code is so:

```
  public static void getAnimals()
    {
        String animalName[] = new String[1];
        int animalNumber[] = new int[1];
        int lengthOfAnimals;

        animalName[0] = "Null";
        animalNumber[0] = 0;

        while (!animalName[animalName.length - 1].equals("EXTERMINATE"))
        {


            animalName[animalName.length - 1] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name an animal?");
            String numLeft = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many are left?");
            animalNumber[animalNumber.length - 1] = Integer.parseInt(numLeft);

            if (animalName[animalName.length - 1].equals("EXTERMINATE"))
            {
                break;
            }

            else
            {

                System.out.println(animalName[animalName.length - 1]);
                animalName = expandName(animalName);
                animalNumber = expandNumber(animalNumber);

            }               
        }




    }

    public static String[] expandName(String animalName[])
    {

        String animalNameExpanded[] = new String[animalName.length + 1];

        for (int a = 0; a <= animalName.length - 1; a++)
        {
            animalNameExpanded[a] =  animalName[a];
        }


        return animalNameExpanded;
    }

    public static int[] expandNumber(int animalNumber[])
    {
        int animalNumberExpanded[] = new int[animalNumber.length + 1];

        for (int a = 0; a <= animalNumber.length - 1; a++)
        {
            animalNumberExpanded[a] =  animalNumber[a];
        }

        return animalNumberExpanded;
    }
```

Now when this runs the value that get puts into animalName and animalNumber is now null. What is going on and how do I fix this.

Comment: I see no `main` method. How do you run these methods? To which class do they belong?

Comment: the main method just calls the getAnimals() method. followed by system exit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String animalNameExpanded[] = new String[animalName.length + 1];
```

creates a new array all of whose entries are `null`. You then copy the values from the old array over, filling all entries but the last one, which remains `null`.

Add a `animalNameExpanded[animalName.length] = "Null";` after the copying, so that

```
while (!animalName[animalName.length - 1].equals("EXTERMINATE"))
```

doesn't read a `null` from the array in the next round.

Answer (score 2):

What @Daniel said, but also this what the [Arrays.copyOf(T[], int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5b%5d,%20int%29) method is for. Check the docs for how it handles larger/smaller sizes.

Also, really seems like you want an array of `Animal` objects, rather than separate arrays for different properties.

#### Edit

Actually, Daniel's suggestion doesn't seem like great style either.  Easier to use a null-safe comparison:

`while (!"EXTERMINATE".equals(animalName[animalName.length - 1]))`

Comment: Ditto on the comparison change.